# Error message when building gimp normalmap-plugin

Tags: make, gimp

I want to install this [gimp-normalmap plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gimp-normalmap/downloads) on my Ubuntu 18.04 system by downloading and unpacking the *gimp-normalmap-1.2.3.tar.bz2* file and running the `make` command in the unpacked folder. Then I get his error message:

```
gcc -c -O3 -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 gtkglext-1.0 gimp-2.0` normalmap.c
Package gimp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gimp-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gimp-2.0' found
normalmap.c:26:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile.linux:26: recipe for target 'normalmap.o' failed
make: *** [normalmap.o] Error 1
```

The install instructions include:

```
The only required packages that must be installed to build the plugin
(besides Gtk+ and the GIMP) are:

  1) gimp version 2.4 or later
  2) pkg-config version 0.14 or later
  3) gtkglext version 0.7.1 or later
  4) GLEW version 1.3.3 or later

You will need to install the development packages for your distribution for
Gtk+, Glib, gtkglext, GLEW and GIMP.
```

I did install all of those and checked by searching for each package with `dpkg-query -l *package*`
When entering `dpkg-query -l *gtk+*` nothing turns up (which is normal I guess) and `dpkg-query -l *gtk*` shows a long list of which I don't know what to do with.

GIMP is installed via the Software Center, not via `apt-get` because the latter one installs an outdated version.

EDIT:

I just installed `libgimp2.0-dev` by executing `sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev` and now I get this new error message when executing `make`:

```
gcc -c -O3 -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 gtkglext-1.0 gimp-2.0` normalmap.c
gcc -c -O3 -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 gtkglext-1.0 gimp-2.0` preview3d.c
gcc -c -O3 -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 gtkglext-1.0 gimp-2.0` scale.c
gcc  normalmap.o preview3d.o scale.o `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 gtkglext-1.0 gimp-2.0 gimpui-2.0` -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGLEW -o normalmap
/usr/bin/ld: normalmap.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sqrtf@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.linux:17: recipe for target 'normalmap' failed
make: *** [normalmap] Error 1
```

Comment: How exactly did you install the packages listed? it looks like `pkg-config` can't find at least the `libgtk2.0-dev` and `libgimp2.0-dev` packages

Comment: Wait, how did you know that `libgimp2.0-dev` must be installed? I just checked and it wasn't. So I installed it, tried `make` again and now I get a different error message. I will update my post.

Comment: The new error appears to indicate an omission in the `Makefile.linux` - open it in a text editor and add `-lm` to the end of the `LIBS` (after `-L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGLEW`)

Comment: Awesome, that solved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @EVARATE How can this be SOLVED, when there are no ANSWER ?

Comment: Instead of editing the title to "solved", you should add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- Install `libgimp2.0-dev`
- Add `-lm` to the end of the `LIBS` after `-L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGLEW`

Thanks to @steeldriver for providing the solution.